# How to stop DIV larger than viewport from scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a DIV (a container element).

In it are some elements I would like to fade-in and fade-out (depending on which direction users are scrolling). This is no problem.

See embedded code snippet for demo.

## Problem

Note the fading black area in the demo; I would like to keep this at the top while fading it (by scrolling some distance).

During fade-in and fade-out of such elements I would like to keep the parent container (DIV) from moving (vertically) until the fade-ins or fade-outs have completed. And this part is what forms a problem for me.

## Update 11-03-2017

I have updated my code with an example which seems to run okay in Chrome (makes it stick using negative `marginTop` for pulling up a `div` (when scrolling up) and positive `top` for pushing down a `div` (when scrolling down). But in runs very 'crappy' in e.g. Edge or Firefox (`scroll`-event fired after scrolling makes it lag behind).

## What I have tried

- I have tried using `position: sticky`. This uses `position: relative` first, then `position: fixed` so it does not quite do what I want.
- I have tried using 'position: fixed'. Of course then the parent container DIV does stick to the viewport. But then, because its height is larger than that of the viewport it does not work the way I intended, e.g. if a user scrolls to 50% of the height of the large container, this scrollTop gets lost by using 'position: fixed'.
- I have tried using 'position: fixed' in combination with 'scroll' event and marginTop CSS-property (and also just the 'top' CSS property). I get weird results with this. Also the 'scroll' event is always executed after the user scrolls a certain amount of pixels. So if it would work one would probably get a 'laggy' experience.
- I have searched for jQuery plugins and such but they too rely on 'position: fixed' and are thus also limited.
- I have tried ScrollMagic and simultaneously executed tweens using GreenSock's TimelineMax. Such as one tween for the fade-in and fade-out and one tween which animates the marginTop (again) or top again to compensate for the scrolled distance with 'position: absolute' and 'position: relative' too.
- I have tried just capturing mousewheel events and scroll programmaticaly then (so I can choose to not scroll). It is an option of course. But I would really like a scrollbar. The mobile experience lags behind because when one does programmatic scrolling one cannot use e.g. 'double tap' gesture.
- I have tried a lot of things and lots of variations of those things.

## Code (embedded snippet) - updated 11-03-2017

Code works crappy in browsers which aren't Chrome (!)

```js
var $window = $(window);
// Element which needs to fade in and out.
var $fadingblack = $("#fadingblack");
// Parent element of fading element.
var $scrollcontainer = $("#scrollcontainer");

// Last scrollTop-value.
var lastScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
var lockForFade = false;

$window.on('scroll',
  // Function which is to be called after user scrolls.
  function() {
    // Current scrollTop value.
    var currentScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
    // Y-coordinate of element which needs to fade.  
    var scrollTopStart = $fadingblack.position().top;
    // Y-coordinate of end of element which needs to fade.
    var scrollTopEndDown = scrollTopStart + $fadingblack.height();
    var scrollTopEndUp = scrollTopStart - $fadingblack.height();
    // Has element which needs to fade scrolled into view.

    // Does the fading itself.
    function doFade($el, $parent, lastScrollTop, currentScrollTop, scrollTopStart, scrollTopEnd) {
      // Curent opacity for fade; determined by scroll position.
      //var currentOpacity = (currentScrollTop - scrollTopStart) / (scrollTopEnd - scrollTopStart);
      var currentOpacity;


      // Temporary variables for scrollTop.
      var theTop;
      var fadeCompleted;

      function undoPushAndScroll() {
        // Save the amount of pixels the parent element has been pushed down.
        var savedTop = $parent.position().top;
        // Then reset this 'push amount'.
        $parent.css("top", 0);
        // And scroll the pushed down amount of pixels back upwards.
        $window.scrollTop(currentScrollTop - savedTop);
        currentScrollTop -= savedTop;
      }

      function undoPullAndScroll() {
        // Save the amount of pixels the parent element has been pulled up.
        var savedTop = parseFloat($parent.css('marginTop'));
        // Then reset this 'pull amount'.
        $parent.css("marginTop", 0);
        // And scroll the pulled up amount of pixels back downwards.
        $window.scrollTop(currentScrollTop - savedTop);
        currentScrollTop -= savedTop;
      }

      function undoPullAndDoPush() {
        var savedMarginTop = parseFloat($parent.css('marginTop'));

        $parent.css('marginTop', 0);
        $window.scrollTop(currentScrollTop - savedMarginTop);
        currentScrollTop -= savedMarginTop;

        // Determine difference between start of fade (Y-value) and current scrollTop (Y-value).
        var theTop = Math.abs(scrollTopStart - currentScrollTop); // + savedMarginTop;
        // Push the parent element down that same difference.
        $parent.css("top", theTop);
      }

      function undoPushAndDoPull() {
        // Save the amount of pixels the parent element has been pushed down.
        var savedTop = $parent.position().top;

        $parent.css('top', 0);
        $window.scrollTop(currentScrollTop - savedTop);
        currentScrollTop -= savedTop;
        // User has scrolled up.
        // Determine difference between start of fade (Y-value) and current scrollTop (Y-value).
        var theTop = Math.abs(scrollTopStart - currentScrollTop);
        // Pull the parent element up that same difference.
        $parent.css("marginTop", -theTop);
      }



      if (lastScrollTop < currentScrollTop) {
        // User has scrolled down.
        undoPullAndDoPush();

        //currentOpacity = Math.abs(currentScrollTop - scrollTopStart) / $el.height();

        fadePercent = Math.abs(currentScrollTop + $parent.position().top - scrollTopStart) / $el.height();
        currentOpacity = fadePercent;

        // Fade to current opacity immediately.
        $el.fadeTo(0, currentOpacity);


        // Determine if fade has completed (must scroll at least the height of the fading element).
        fadeCompleted = ($parent.position().top >= $el.height());
        if (fadeCompleted) {
          // Then immediately set opacity to 1.
          $el.fadeTo(0, 1);
          // Fade has completed.
          undoPushAndScroll();
          lockForFade = false;
        }
      } else if (lastScrollTop > currentScrollTop) {
        // User has scrolled up.
        undoPushAndDoPull();


        fadePercent = Math.abs(currentScrollTop + parseFloat($parent.css('marginTop')) - scrollTopStart) / $el.height();
        currentOpacity = 1 - fadePercent;
        // Fade to current opacity immediately.
        $el.fadeTo(0, currentOpacity);

        // Determine if fade has completed (must scroll at least the height of the fading element).
        fadeCompleted = (-parseFloat($parent.css('marginTop')) >= $el.height());
        if (fadeCompleted) {
          // Then immediately set opacity to 0.
          $el.fadeTo(0, 0);
          // Fade has completed.
          undoPullAndScroll();
          lockForFade = false;
        }
      }
    }

    if (lastScrollTop < currentScrollTop) {
      // Scrolling down in fade area.
      if (!lockForFade && currentScrollTop >= scrollTopStart && lastScrollTop < scrollTopStart) {
        if (parseFloat($fadingblack.css('opacity')) < 1) {
          lockForFade = true;
        }
      }
      if (lockForFade) {
        doFade(
          $fadingblack,
          $scrollcontainer,
          lastScrollTop,
          currentScrollTop,
          scrollTopStart,
          scrollTopEndDown);
      }
    } else if (lastScrollTop > currentScrollTop) {
      // Scrolling up in fade area.
      if (!lockForFade && currentScrollTop <= scrollTopStart && lastScrollTop > scrollTopStart) {
        if (parseFloat($fadingblack.css('opacity')) > 0) {
          lockForFade = true;
        }
      }
      if (lockForFade) {
        console.log('dofade up');
        doFade(
          $fadingblack,
          $scrollcontainer,
          lastScrollTop,
          currentScrollTop,
          scrollTopStart,
          scrollTopEndUp);
      }
    }


    // Save last scrollTop-value for next scroll-event-call.
    lastScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#scrollcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.red,
.blue,
.black {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
}

.red,
.blue {
  height: 300px;
}

.black {
  height: 600px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

#fadingblack {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scrollcontainer">
  <div class="red">BEGIN</div>
  <div class="blue">Fading black area is ahead...</div>
  <div id="fadingblack" class="black">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">END</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want the 'fadingblack' div to stick once it's in view, then scroll through the fade, and once it's done fading, continue bringing other divs into view?

Comment: @AmericanSlime Yes, that's exactly what I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably no way to *really* - in a more natural kind of way - prevent a `div` which uses `position: fixed` - or even `position: sticky` (which uses relative positioning at first *and* later when it sticks fixed positioning) - and has a larger size than viewport from scrolling when you want it to at a certain point.

Still, the goal of my question (stop scrolling to fade some `div` elements) I can answer myself with some lines of code. In summary: use `marginTop` of a `div` to pull up some `div` child elements of a `div` which uses fixed positioning.

I do have at least one other question (maybe two) relating to this code (but not to the prevention of scrolling). But that are other questions which I can ask as new questions.

I will accept my own answer for now. If someone has a better or more 'natural' idea concerning this question - which I somehow doubt - I will happily change my acceptance to that answer.

```js
var $window = $(window);
var $document = $(document);
// Element which needs to fade in and out.
var $fadingblack = $("#fadingblack");
var $scrolldistract = $("#scrolldistract");
var $scrollsviascrolldistract = $("#scrollsviascrolldistract");
// Pulls up the child divs of #scrollsviascrolldistract, under it.
var $puller = $("#puller");


// Start of fading area (Y-value).
var scrollTopStart = $fadingblack.position().top;
// And of course the Y-value of the end of the fading area.
var scrollTopEnd = scrollTopStart + $fadingblack.height();

// Maximum scrollTop-value (when scrollbar is at 100%).
var lastScrollTop = $document.height() - $window.height();

// Amount of scrolled pixels (vertically) including amount scrolled while
// the fading element is fading.
var scrollAmountWithFadeAmount = $document.height + $fadingblack.height();
// Setting height does not quite work for an empty div,
// so we are using some padding.
$scrolldistract.css("paddingTop", scrollAmountWithFadeAmount);
// Percentage of which we have scrolled (1 = 100%).
var currentScrollTopP;
// Current scrollTop value.
var realCurY;

$(function() {
  // Off you go code...

  function doScrollOrFade() {
    currentScrollTopP = Math.ceil($window.scrollTop() / lastScrollTop * 100) / 100;
    realCurY = currentScrollTopP * lastScrollTop;

    if (realCurY >= scrollTopStart && realCurY <= scrollTopEnd) {
      // Current realCurY dictates we are in fade area.
      // So scroll the fading area into view at top of browser viewport.
      $puller.css("marginTop", -scrollTopStart);
      // Determine opacity percentage.
      var fadePercent = (realCurY - scrollTopStart) / (scrollTopEnd - scrollTopStart);
      // Fade to current opacity immediately.
      $fadingblack.fadeTo(0, fadePercent);
    } else {
      // We are outside of the fading area and in scroll-mode.
      if (realCurY < scrollTopStart) {
        // We are somewhere before the fading area, so set opacity to 0.
        $fadingblack.fadeTo(0, 0);
      } else {
        // We are somewhere after the fading area, so set opacity to 1.
        $fadingblack.fadeTo(0, 1);
      }

      if (realCurY > scrollTopEnd) {
        // We have passed the fading area. So we have an amount
        // of pixels we wasted on the opacity changes.
        // Correct it here.
        $puller.css("marginTop", -realCurY + $fadingblack.height());
      } else {
        $puller.css("marginTop", -realCurY);
      }
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(doScrollOrFade);
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(doScrollOrFade);

  $window.on('resize orientationchange', function(e) {
    // On resize or orientation change recalculate some stuff.
    lastScrollTop = $document.height() - $window.height();
    scrollAmountWithFadeAmount = $document.height + $fadingblack.height();
    $scrolldistract.css("paddingTop", scrollAmountWithFadeAmount);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(doScrollOrFade);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#scrollsviascrolldistract {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

#scrolldistract {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 2100px;
  height: 0px;
}

#puller {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

img {
  display: block;
}

.black,
.red,
.blue {
  border: solid 1px yellow;
  font-size: 32pt;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!--
For mobile support use viewport meta-tag inside <head>:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes">
-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scrolldistract"></div>

<div id="scrollsviascrolldistract">
  <!-- For pulling up the red, blue and fading area -->
  <div id="puller"></div>
  <div class="red">BEGIN</div>
  <div class="blue">Fading black area is ahead...</div>
  <div id="fadingblack" class="black">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="red">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="blue">END</div>
</div>
```